# An error occurred when writing Flutter's PushNamed parameter transfer, but the problem was still not solved after inquiring a lot of information

Tags: flutter, flutter-android

I'm building a simple flutter app and I'm having trouble passing parameters using named routes.
I got the error message

```
Receiver: Closure: (dynamic) => Home
Tried calling: new MyApp.<anonymous closure>(Instance of 'StatelessElement', arguments: _LinkedHashMap len:4)
Found: new MyApp.<anonymous closure>(dynamic) => Home
```

My main interface code is

```
import 'package:world_time/pages/Library.dart';
import 'package:world_time/pages/home.dart';
import 'package:world_time/pages/choose_location.dart';
import 'package:world_time/pages/loading.dart';
import 'package:world_time/pages/details.dart';
import 'package:world_time/pages/setting.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
    MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

    final routes = {
        '/': (context) => Loading(),
        '/home': (context) => Home(),
        '/setting': (context) => ChangeSetting(),
        '/library': (context) => ChooseLibrary(),
        '/location': (context) => ChooseLocation(),
        '/details': (context,{arguments}) => Details(arguments:arguments),
    };

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            home: Loading(),
            onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
                final String? name = settings.name;
                final Function pageContentBuilder = this.routes[name] as Function;
                if (pageContentBuilder != null) {
                    if (settings.arguments != null) {
                        final Route route = MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => pageContentBuilder(context, arguments: settings.arguments));
                        return route;
                    } else {
                        final Route route = MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => pageContentBuilder(context));
                        return route;
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Automatically load from loading to home, home can navigate setting, library and location. Setting, library and location can all navigate details.
I hope to pass parameters through onGenerateRoute, so that I can easily complete the corresponding data processing in the following pages. But I can't run the whole project now.
I've looked up a lot and I can't figure out the correct code. This is my first time writing a flutter project and I hope to get help.

Comment: In routes the functions are taking a dynamic parameter 'context'. It might help to declare the type of context as BuildContext so your routes look like the following:
'/myRoute': (BuildContext context) => MyWidget(),

Can also pass a function reference in the builders so it's only:
final route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: pageContentBuilder));

Comment: Can you include how are you navigating between routes?

Comment: Automatically load from loading to home, home can navigate setting, library and location. Setting, library and location can all navigate details.